# ODP.net Connection Pooling: ClientID, Client Identifier never changes from first user who logs in

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle10g, connection-pooling, odp.net

**Scenario**: We have an application that is using Oracle 10g and the latest version of ODP.net within an ASP.net application. We are utilizing the .ClientID WriteOnly property on the OracleConnection object to pass in a specific UserID to the database for auditing purposes. When Connection Pooling is disabled, this works perfectly.

When it is enabled, the first person who logs in (ex: USER1) updates a record and the MODIFIED_BY is USER1, but when a different user heads into the website after, thus grabbing the pooled connection, the MODIFIED_BY is still USER1 despite passing in USER2 to the ClientID.

Our database logic is as follows:

We persist a class in an ASP.net session that has our database connection logic in it. On the initial call, this is our constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal connection As String, Optional ByVal oracleClientID As String = "")
        MyBase.New()
        _oracleConnection = New OracleConnection(connection)
        _clientID = oracleClientID
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here’s the gist of the code to open connection and close, dispose:

```
Try
    _OraCmd = New OracleCommand(command, _oracleConnection)
    With _OraCmd
        .BindByName = True
        .Parameters.Clear()
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        _oracleConnection.Open()
            If _clientID <> "" Then _oracleConnection.ClientId = _clientID
        Dim OraDadpt As New OracleDataAdapter(_OraCmd)
            '' Logic to get data
        OraDadpt.Fill(ds)
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
Finally

    ClearParameters()
    _OraCmd.Dispose()
    _oracleConnection.Close()
End Try
```

The thought is that since the connection is pooled, there is an assumed call to a LOGON Trigger that never happens and the Client Identifier is never set again. ORACLE's documentation, however, states that the ClientID is used for exactly what we are trying to do.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why the SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CLIENT_IDENTIFIER') is not being set to a new USERID that is passed into the ClientID when connection pooling is used within our .NET application with ODP.net? Is this a database setting, a listener setting?

### Update

We forwarded the issue to Oracle. In doing so, we had to create a small test app that mimicked the issue. When doing that, on my localhost -- everything worked perfectly using Visual Studio's built-in Cassini web server. **With IIS, the issue occurs.**

**UPDATE**

Determined that IIS wasn't the problem. It was package variables not being cleared out due to connections that were pooled being re-used, in essence, what pooling is supposed to do. We solved this by using DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE).

Comment: You mention the LOGON trigger. What exactly is the purpose of the LOGON trigger in your setup? And can you post its code.

Comment: We don't have one. ODP.net should be handling that via the .ClientID property. From everything I've read, when the logon to the database happens -- ODP sets the SYS_CONTEXT with the .ClientID.

Comment: Yes, ODP.NET sets the SYS_CONTEXT. But this doesn't have anything to do with a LOGON trigger, which is something different. Can you show the connection string you're using for connection pooling? Possibly you're not using the ODP.NET connection pool (which resets the Client ID when the connection is returned to the pool).

Comment: The connection string is simply: "data source=dataSource;user id=user;password=pass;" - Pooling is defaulted to on from what I understand. I tried using all the Min and Max Pool size properties, etc with no luck.

Comment: You have my condolences for being in oracle hell.

Comment: Hey How about setting DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER when the connection is opened

Comment: That's what .ClientID is supposed to do in this case.

Comment: are you using iis 6 or 7 ? if 7 are what is your application pool set to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using DBMS.Rest_Package before closing the connections.

The problem I think is with pooling turned on ODP is keeping the connection thus as each user opens and closes a connection with ODP, pooling is keeping the session package variables in memory; until the connection times out.  However, since the time/out and re-establish of a connection from the database to the pool only occurs AFTER a connection is RETURNED to the pool, you're operating with someone else's session data.

Comment: What about DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE)?

Comment: That's actually a better approach. It doesn't have a memory leak that DMBS.Reset_Package had nor other overhead.  You might also want to call that BEFORE you execute your SQL instead of after and before the close.  If for some reason the call to the package hangs and you're not able to execute the next line of code, you will not reset the session.  If the pool  listener times out the connection and releases it back to the pool, you'll have a connection with global package variables which might get picked up by the next call that gets that connection.  I'd hate to have to debug that one later.

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5809900747879 may help out.  It indicates using global package variables with connection pooling isn't wise to begin with. However, if you must, using the reinitialize you've mentioned should eliminate package persistance when the connection is returned to the pool.

Comment: After extensive testing, package variables were determined to be the issue. While it isn't a far reaching solution, DBMS_SESSION.MODIFY_PACKAGE_STATE(DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE) is working right now.

Comment: **Guideline:** Don't use global public package variables with connection pooling.  Why? Because when you .close the connection, it really isn't closed.  It's made available to the next request by the pool; but the pool maintains the connection.  Since the connection is maintained all DB session variables are maintained.  This includes package globals, temp tables, and instances of objects.  So when the 2nd person gets the connection you just released and attempts to access the same packages you did, they get a dirty DB session.  This also means **anon block doesn't fire again!**

Answer (score 1):

This works fine both with pooling on and off. The ClientId and ClientInfo on the Oracle Session do not update until a command is executed.

Could you verify your if statement is correct? If _clientID <> "" Then _oracleConnection.ClientId = _clientID. Even when you close the connection, the clientId will still stay the same. Not sure where your setting/getting _clientId when you pass that into your method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClientId test = new TestClientId();
        test.DoSomething("FirstClientId");
        test.DoSomething("ChangedClientId");
    }
}

public class TestClientId
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The connection string. 
    /// </summary>
    private const string ConnString = "DATA SOURCE=//server:port/service_name;USER ID=user;PASSWORD=pswd;";

    /// <summary>
    /// The oracle connection.
    /// </summary>
    private OracleConnection connection;

    /// <summary>
    /// The oracle session id.
    /// </summary>
    private long sid;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TestClientId"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public TestClientId()
    {
        this.connection = new OracleConnection(ConnString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the client id of the oracle connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientId">The client id.</param>
    public void DoSomething(string clientId)
    {            
        this.connection.Open();
        this.sid = this.GetSessionId(this.connection);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
        {
            this.connection.ClientInfo = clientId;
            this.connection.ClientId = clientId;                
        }

        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from dual", this.connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        this.connection.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the session id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="con">The connection object.</param>
    /// <returns>The current oracle session id.</returns>
    public int GetSessionId(OracleConnection con)
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') from dual";
        object sid = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return Convert.ToInt32(sid);
    }
}
```

Comment: In our case, it only works on the first logon to the database. Subsequent calls within the limit of the pool timeout are all the first login user's name. If we allow the timeout period to pass, the connection dies and the next user in has their name in the ClientID. It's as if the connection never closes. But I am closing it.

Comment: It's actually working for me. I've tried the 10.x api against an 11g database, and the 11.x api against a 10g database. Both ways work. The issue I had was that I need to execute a command before the ClientId or ClientInfo actually updated. I tested with Pooling=true and Pooling=false, both worked.

Comment: Per your previous question, we pass the ClientID into the constructor and set it to a private variable. Then access the private variable and set it to the ClientID when we make the Execute call.

Comment: This is what is leading me to believing this must be some sort of server problem. We are forwarding this case to Oracle to see if that may be the case. I tried your solution above, exactly as you have it with no luck.

Comment: While I was googling earlier, I saw a user with a similiar issue on Oracle forums, and they had mentioned that they had re-installed odp.net or odac and it resolved the issue. I find that hard to believe for this case. The assembly is there, it should work. That might be worth a try though.

Comment: We have this same problem across 2 servers, a production and development server on different boxes. We updated everything to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, in that case open up a case with Oracle on metalink if you have an account with them. They've been quick in responding to some .net issues I've had in the past related to Oracle.DataAccess api.

Answer (score 1):

The ClientId is reset only on the connection close and if you are closing then its bound to be reset.

Connection pooling helps the database server to timeout an idle session and use the connection to service an active session. The idle logical session remains open, and the physical connection is automatically reestablished when the next request comes from that session. So is the connection actually closed ?

So it would be good to set the Session identifier by **DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER**

Hope this helps

Comment: Based on the above code, the .Close() is hit on every request. Your logic would seem correct however. It does act is if the connection is never closed. From the testing I've done, the .Close is always hit.

Comment: Setting the Identifier, then clearing it out should have worked, so we are now focusing on this being a potential listener issue.

Comment: You are right that it hits the **Close** but in connection pooling its never closed but returned to the pool and when the next request sets in the same connection is used. So in your current context its always using the same connection as of USER1

Comment: Except that's exactly what ClientID is supposed to do... reset the Client Identifier even when grabbing an existing pooled connection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very dangerous to me to keep a reference to a database connection in your session. The idea of the connection pool is that a request borrows a connection for the duration of the request. When the request completes, the connection goes back to the pool. The connection will then be reused for more requests from different users.

I suspect that all sorts of nasty things happen when you store a connection in your session. You probably use the connection while it's being concurrently used by another request. Or you might get a closed connection because the connectin pool has to decide to close it.

Furthmore, the LOGON trigger is probably only executed when the database connection is created for the first time but is not executed again when the connection is reused for a different request or a different user.

To fix your problem, grab a database connection at the beginning of every request and explicitly set the Client ID (and/or execute the code that's run by the LOGON trigger). Then use this connection for the duration of the request. But don't store it anywhere after the request has finished.

That way, your connection is always properly initialized with the current user's context. And you adhere to the rules of the connection pool.

Comment: The connection isn't actually maintained open in the session. It is simply the class that contains the functionality. The connection is opened and closed for each operation.

Comment: We actually do grab a database connection at the beginning of every request, set the .ClientID, run whatever operation, then close down the connection.

Comment: I just tried this, and see the same issue as you. I don't see anything wrong with the way your connecting. I'm looking into an answer now.

Comment: I suppose the question is whether the newest ODP.net version works alongside 10g Release 2 in this capacity.

Comment: Something seems to be terpermental about it. I had an older app that when connected to an 11g database, updated the ClientId with no issue right after opening the connection. Now I'm a 11.2 version of the Oracle.DataAccess api against 11g database, and not having any luck with it updating the ClientId or ClientInfo. The previous app that worked, may have been using the 10.2 DataAccess reference.

Answer (score 0):

When connection pooling is enabled, which is good and of course the way to go in an ASP.NET scenario (and in most scenarios in fact), you should not **store** any db connection. You must open and close connections when you need it.

Here is a link about SQL Server, but it's the same with Oracle that explains it: [SqlConnection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y200)

So the code you need to use when calling Oracle should be something like this, anywhere in your app, whenyou need it:

```
Using connection As New OracleConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    ' Do work here; connection closed on following line.
End Using
```

The thing is: you cannot have connection pooling enabled with specific user information in the connection string. So I suggest you implement your auditing code without using the connection string.